# Rails DELETE putting a period before :id

Tags: ruby, routes, period

I'm making a simple calorie counter, using http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html as a reference. I'm trying to add a Delete button, but every time I try to run it, I hit an error:
`No route matches [DELETE] "/calorieinput.1"`

I know the issue is that there's a period instead of a slash, which has been a common occurrence in this app. I fixed it before in the `form_for` but there isn't one for DELETE. I'll try to add everything needed, I am new to posting so I'm sorry in advance if I forget anything.

```
def destroy
  @calinput = Calorie.find(params[:id])
  @calinput.destroy

  redirect_to calorieinput_index_path
end
```

`Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
calorieinput_index GET    /calorieinput(.:format)          calorieinput#index
                   POST   /calorieinput(.:format)          calorieinput#create
  new_calorieinput GET    /calorieinput/new(.:format)      calorieinput#new
 edit_calorieinput GET    /calorieinput/:id/edit(.:format) calorieinput#edit
      calorieinput GET    /calorieinput/:id(.:format)      calorieinput#show
                   PATCH  /calorieinput/:id(.:format)      calorieinput#update
                   PUT    /calorieinput/:id(.:format)      calorieinput#update
                   DELETE /calorieinput/:id(.:format)      calorieinput#destroy
              root GET    /                                welcome#index`

```
<% @calinput.each do |calorieinputs| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= calorieinputs.food %></td>
    <td><%= calorieinputs.calories %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'View', calorieinput_path(calorieinputs) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_calorieinput_path(calorieinputs) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', calorieinput_index_path(calorieinputs),
            method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this post?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the issue was the wrong path in my DELETE link. I was referencing the Index instead of the Show route. Sorry to waste your time people.